# Want to remove a class along with adding slideUp in siblings tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with side-nav which comprises of ul and li tags.

Looks like:

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:;">Mobile</a>
</li>
<li class="uk-nav-header">
    PLATFORM SPECIFIC GUIDES
</li>
<li class="uk-active uk-magento" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="demo">
    <a href="/docs/magento">Magento Extension</a>
    <ul class="uk-nav-sub uk-nav-parent-mag hidden" >  
        <li><a href="#step1">1.Install Magento Extension</a></li>
        <li><a href="#step2">2.Configure extension</a></li>
        <li><a href="#step3">3.Launch Widgets</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq">&nbsp;&nbsp;Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>   
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here I want to click on heading "Magento Extension" which should usually slidesup is siblings subheading.
But now when I click on heading it refreshes page and subheading arent slideup.

Code I am using is:

```
$(".uk-magento").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().siblings().hasClass('.uk-nav-parent-mag').removeClass("hidden", 400, "easeInBack");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is hasClass() returns boolean value, not a jQuery object so the next chained method call(`.removeClass()`) will fail.

Also the `uk-nav-parent-mag` selector is wrong.

```js
$(".uk-magento").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.uk-nav-parent-mag').removeClass("hidden", 400, "easeInBack");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">Mobile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="uk-nav-header">
    PLATFORM SPECIFIC GUIDES
  </li>
  <li class="uk-active uk-magento" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="demo">
    <a href="/docs/magento">Magento Extension</a>
    <ul class="uk-nav-sub uk-nav-parent-mag hidden">

      <li><a href="#step1">1.Install Magento Extension</a></li>
      <li><a href="#step2">2.Configure extension</a></li>
      <li><a href="#step3">3.Launch Widgets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#faq">&nbsp;&nbsp;Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code works well. But when I click on heading "Magento Extension" its href targets it to "/docs/magento" and page is refreshed . So I cant find any removeClass action

Comment: @AkashPathak is there any error in your browser console

Comment: No, I cant see any console error. But its default function. A li tag cant do 2 things at a time. It has to target a page and along with that have to removeClass in its siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM structure seems very complicated for what you are trying to achieve.

parent(), siblings() and hasClass() should be used sparingly and only in situations where complex DOM element hierarchies are unavoidable.

Without more information it's difficult to tell how this side-nav fits into the context of the rest of your page but here's how you could simplify things a bit:

HTML:

```
<li> 
  <a href="javascript:;">Mobile</a> 
</li> 
<li class="uk-nav-header"> PLATFORM SPECIFIC GUIDES </li> 
<li class="uk-active uk-magento" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="demo"> Magento Extension</li>
<ul class="uk-nav-sub uk-nav-parent-mag hidden" >
  <li><a href="#step1">1.Install Magento Extension</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#step2">2.Configure extension</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#step3">3.Launch Widgets</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#faq">&nbsp;&nbsp;Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(".uk-magento").on("click", function() {
  $(".uk-nav-parent-mag").toggleClass("hidden", 400, "easeInBack");
});
```

Demo link:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPYKea